# Ember Custom View Creating a Chart View

Tags: ember.js

Im in the process of creating a view for a chart with jquery.flot. So I created a view and in my template call it like so:

```
{{view GraphView graphableBinding="graphables"}}
```

Problem is the graphables object is an array and the observers do not fire which notifies me of changes to the array within the view.

I thought about using a CollectionView, however, the array itself doesnt affect the html result of the template but rather needs to fire a $.plot() command on the container div with the new data array. Any thoughts on how I would implement this sort of thing?

Comment: The probelm is likely in your view class. Can you post the code of GraphView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@each` key lets you observe changes to the contents of the array.  See the ember.js guide regarding this feature:

http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/